# Size classes and Auto Layout confusion with multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard, size-classes

I created my first app without using size classes and auto layout. Now i'll be making a 2nd app but i'll use size classes+auto layout. So pardon my confusion.

In Xcode's, Assistant Editor preview, I will use all the device sizes for the preview, all iPhones and iPad, iPad PRO.

My understanding is I can use 1 Main.Storyboard for all the storyboards of all devices with the preview storyboards.

However, when it comes to coding, can I also use just 1 view controller.h and view controller.m file for all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if you can use a single storyboard for all the devices, what makes you think you would not be able to use a single view controller?

Comment: In Objective-C, do I just have to use for example...  if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==480.0f){

Do I just have to use the above and change all the size in the code? Is that how it works with 1 view controller for all devices?

Otherwise, when I'm writing my code, how will I know which device is being affected, whether iPhone 4s OR iPad PRO?

Comment: In general, the assumption is that you design the user interface in the storyboard.  Which device is being affected depends on the size class that you are designing for.  If the size class is h: any and w: any, then you are designing for all devices.  If you set the size class specifically, then you are designing for a specific subset of devices.